# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException when trying run mockito junit5 test with maven

Tags: mockito, junit5

I am using JUNIT5 and Mockito. I want to write a ParameterizedTest. 
When trying to run tests using IntelliJ I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 66 more
```

The following parametrized test I want to execute

```html
    @Test
    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(value = Money.Status.class, mode = EnumSource.Mode.EXCLUDE, names = {"deleted", "pending"})
    void testMoneyStates(Money.Status status) {
        System.out.println("Hurray " + status);
    }
```

I run it under IntelliJ 2019.3
I have following dependencies in pom:

```
        <!-- Junit Mockito Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
          <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
          <version>RELEASE</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
          <version>5.6.0-M1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the error because my JUnit dependency and Junit-Jupiter-Params dependencies were on different incompetible versions. I tried multiple versions and the below versions worked for me. mockito-junit-jupiter version 3.2.4 uses Junit 5.4.2 version.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```